# GUI doesn't display when handling command line arguments

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

The problem is that program just handles the command line arguments and exits, instead of displaying a GUI too.

For example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gint print_cmd_arg(GApplication *app, GApplicationCommandLine *app_cmd, int *argc)
{
    if (*argc > 1)
    {
        char **argv = g_application_command_line_get_arguments(app_cmd, argc);
        GFile *file = g_file_new_for_commandline_arg(argv[1]);

        if (g_file_query_exists(file, NULL))
        {
            char *text;
            g_file_load_contents(file, NULL, &text, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            g_print("%s", text);
            g_free(text);
            g_object_unref(file);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            g_print("File \'%s\' does not exist.\n", argv[1]);
            g_object_unref(file);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 2;
}

static void activation(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Test");
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), NULL);

    GtkWidget *button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Quit");
    g_signal_connect_swapped(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_destroy), window);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), button);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int status;
    GtkApplication *test = gtk_application_new("this.is.only.a.test", G_APPLICATION_NON_UNIQUE | G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE);
    g_signal_connect(test, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activation), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(G_APPLICATION(test), "command-line", G_CALLBACK(print_cmd_arg), &argc);
    status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(test), argc, argv);
    return status;
}
```

Try running this, you'll see that this program completely ignores function `activation`.

What I want this program to do is to both handle command line arguments and display GUI.

Also, I know I'm supposed to use [g_application_command_line_set_exit_status()](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GApplicationCommandLine.html#g-application-command-line-set-exit-status) in `print_cmd_arg` instead of `return`s, but I don't know how to do this and get compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling command line is a complex subject in the GtkApplication/GApplication context due to added flexibility.

If you are "overriding" the command line handling/parsing then a variety of methods to do so will be available.

Information on this subject is somewhat scattered in the documentation. Some of it is here:

1. https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication
2. https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication/CommandLine
3. https://developer.gnome.org/gio//2.30/GApplication.html#g-application-run
4. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html
5. https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html

From **1)** you can read:

> Dealing with the command line
>
> Normally, GtkApplication will assume that arguments passed on the
>   command line are files to be opened. If no arguments are passed, then
>   it assumes that an application is being launched to show its main
>   window or an empty document. In the case that files were given, you
>   will receive these files (in the form of GFile) from the open signal.
>   Otherwise you will receive an activate signal. It is recommended that
>   new applications make use of this default handling of command line
>   arguments.
>
> If you want to deal with command line arguments in more advanced ways,
>   there are several (complementary) mechanisms by which you can do this.

And an important bit is:

> Note in particular that it is possible to use action activations
>   instead of activate or open. It is perfectly reasonable that an
>   application could start without an activate signal ever being emitted.
>   **activate is only supposed to be the default "started with no options" signal**. Actions are meant to be used for anything else.

So, there are various ways to handle arguments. The questions goes to how and what are you trying to do. If the arguments are files then maybe handle them with the `open` signal and avoid handling the command line.

To solve the actual problem, as you may conclude, activate won't be fired but you can do it by using `g_application_activate` in your command line callback, e.g.:

```
static gint print_cmd_arg(GApplication *app, GApplicationCommandLine *app_cmd, int *argc)
{
    /* ADD THIS TO YOUR CODE */
    g_application_activate(app);
    /* ENDS HERE */

    if (*argc > 1)
    {
        char **argv = g_application_command_line_get_arguments(app_cmd, argc);
        GFile *file = g_file_new_for_commandline_arg(argv[1]);

        if (g_file_query_exists(file, NULL))
        {
            char *text;
            g_file_load_contents(file, NULL, &text, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            g_print("%s", text);
            g_free(text);
            g_object_unref(file);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            g_print("File \'%s\' does not exist.\n", argv[1]);
            g_object_unref(file);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm supposed to return whatever `g_application_run` returns, but if it's never run (we use `g_application_activate` to deal with that), what should my program return?

Comment: You could use, as you referenced, g_application_command_line_set_exit_status(), to inform the application about the return code (or exit code) it should use. your local function i would assume 0 for no error and 1 if so but since you are not using the standards then maybe it's irrelevant.

Comment: Ok... so that's what `g_application_command_line_set_exit_status()` does. Also, please take a look at this [code](https://pastebin.com/naxzKGT1). If you run this program and exit normally, you'll see that it returns `0`. So `g_application_run` is maybe executed after all.

Comment: Sorry for messy copying from the terminal.

Comment: @Hanlon No problem. Just tested and indeed still zero. After reading the documentation this caught my attention: "In the case that the commandline invocation is local, the situation is slightly more complicated. If the commandline invocation results in the mainloop running (ie: because the use-count of the application increased to a non-zero value) then the application is considered to have been 'successful' in a certain sense, and the exit status is always zero.". The subject is complex and i would advise you to avoid going this route unless you have reasons to do so.

Comment: So, it's easier to just use `"open"` signal?

Comment: @Hanlon If your arguments are filenames to be handled by your application then yes, you should use it. unless you want to handle -- flags in the command line interface, you should avoid handling the command line